# How to prevent sql-injection in nodejs and sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sql-injection, sequelize.js

I want to write custom queries using Sequelize, and as far as possible avoid potential issues with SQL Injection. My question is therefore if there exists a secure way of writing custom queries with inserted variables using Sequelize?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Sequelize escapes replacements, which avoids the problem at the heart of SQL injection attacks: unescaped strings. It also supports binding parameters when using SQLite or PostgreSQL, which alleviates the risk further by sending the parameters to the database separately to the query, [as documented here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/raw-queries/#bind-parameter):

> Bind parameters are like replacements. Except replacements are escaped
>   and inserted into the query by sequelize before the query is sent to
>   the database, while bind parameters are sent to the database outside
>   the SQL query text. A query can have either bind parameters or
>   replacements.
>
> Only SQLite and PostgreSQL support bind parameters. Other dialects
>   will insert them into the SQL query in the same way it is done for
>   replacements. Bind parameters are referred to by either $1, $2, ...
>   (numeric) or $key (alpha-numeric). This is independent of the dialect.

Comment: https://snyk.io/blog/sql-injection-orm-vulnerabilities/

Comment: still input validation and sanitization is a good choice. Together with an ORM