# Sequelize where option sql injection?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Is the following sequelize call vulnerable for sql injection?

```
var dataDirectlyFromTheUserWithoutValidation = req.query.filter 
Record.findAll({where: dataDirectlyFromTheUserWithoutValidation})
```

Comment: exercise it. make a PEN test with a bobby tables attack.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes,** for versions below 4.

The library contains a comment in the [source code](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/8a8366b4dde3060145f0037f85b4aad816b94aa3/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js#L1125) of the `SELECT` query composition that states,

> If you use a string, you have to escape it on your own.

Sequelize inserts the values of an `options.where` hash unescaped and unparametrized into a string that gets executed by the destination engine (I checked it only for [MSSQL](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/dialects/mssql/query-generator.js#L868)).

So callers need to take care they sanitize any user input to mitigate a possible sql injection vulnerability in their applications.

Authors [claim to have addressed](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/1ce34286655304360b2775546d8ea2af579810c3/docs/upgrade-to-v4.md) this vulnerability starting from v4. Other vulnerbilities in connection with `ORDER` and `LIMIT` clauses have already been addressed starting from v3.16.

Comment: But above 4.0 it is safe to use without sanitizing/escaping? Warning is still in the source code?

Comment: [its complicated](https://snyk.io/vuln/npm:sequelize:20150517)... and may [depend on the connected rdbms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35668730/1132334). warning is still there, but it applies to calls to an internal helper function that is not directly exposed via `findAll`. given the [past history](https://snyk.io/vuln/npm:sequelize:20160106) of discovered and mitigated vulnerabilities, I would really actually backup and send something like "bye');drop table students;--" to a test database. maybe we can attract one of the original authors to weigh in with an expert's statement.

Comment: I thought it was safe to use unescaped strings if it is in the options object. If you do something like `sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM projects WHERE status = something',`, then anything in that string passed to sequelize.query from user would be vulnerable. The query you have Franken is safe as far as I know.